# Is there a function in Emgucv to find non-zero pixels?

Tags: opencv, pixel, emgucv

There is a function called findNonZero to find the position of non-zero pixels in Opencv. I am wondering is there is something similar in Emgucv?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there dosen't seems to be one but you can always invoke the OpenCV functions directly using the `CvInvoke`.

The syntax to invoke the above mentioned function will be

```
CvInvoke.findNonZero();// pass the suitable parameters in the function suitably
```

This [this post](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) to find out more.

Comment: The issue is that there is no findNonZero or cvfindNonZero in Emgucv. Here is the error: 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' does not contain a definition for 'findNonZero'! Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Find the location of the non-zero pixel
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   src:
    //     The source array
    //
    //   idx:
    //     The output array where the location of the pixels are sorted
    public static void FindNonZero(IInputArray src, IOutputArray idx);
```

invoke it on CvInvoke.FindNonZero(src, outputImage);